# css change property class inside another class

Tags: css

Is it possible change a class property from inside another class? i.e.

```
myText{
property:one;
property:two;
visibility:hidden;
}

myImg{
property:one;
property:two;
}

myImg:hover{
myText{visibility:visible;}
}
```

So when mouse is over myImg myText will display?

Comment: Please show your HTML, as the possibilities of CSS are somewhat limited by the structure of the mark-up (and yes, this is probably possible).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible by using an [adjacent sibling selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html). Suppose that you are using HTML4, the code should be as following:

```
 .myImg:hover + .myText {
        visibility:visible;
 }
```

Moreover, if you are using HTML5, you can simply do like this :

```
 .myImg:hover  .myText {
        visibility:visible;
 }
```

Comment: You SHOULD study "How to use JsFiddle"!!, don't put everything in only CSS panel. So, my code normally works. If it doesn't, it's because you did something wrong.